# To replace all backslashes with forward slashes using sed or python

Tags: python, regex, sed

aim: to replace all backslashes with forward slashes.

actual string:\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu

expected string://test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu

trying to get sed to work for the above is turning out to be quite a task

any thoughts?

**Edit: read as Env variables in Jenkins**
**The Complete use case being: They are passed as Windows UNC Paths via jenkins, need to be mounted on Unix**

In Python on *nix

It behaves differently when tried via variables!, when i read the variables via python, the '\' string is chopped of by the interpreter. i have tried repr(variable) in conjunction with .decode('string_escape') but to no avail.
raw_input() does not help in python on unix

here is main the python script named test1.py

s=re.sub(r'\',r'/',repr(sys.argv[1].decode('string_escape')), 
Which is run as 
python test1.py \test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu
,Output of which is turning out to be 
//test.abc.compath1path1_1123ubntu; 
Why is python thinking '\' cannot be displayed :-( –

Trying via sed now through env variables.

Comment: Can you post the regex you tried?

Comment: here is main the python script named test1.py s=re.sub(r'\\',r'/',repr(sys.argv[1].decode('string_escape')), Which is run as python test1.py \\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu  , Output of which is turning out to be //test.abc.compath1path1_1123ubntu; Why is python thinking '\' cannot be displayed :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated for environment variables.*

You say that the path is in an environment variable (let's say UNC_PATH), so in Python:

```
# test.py
import re, sys

s = re.sub(r'\\', r'/', sys.argv[1])
print s
```

and invoke it like this:

```
$ UNC_PATH=\\\\test.abc.com\\path1\\path1_1\\123\\ubntu
$ python test.py $UNC_PATH
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

For sed, do this:

```
$ echo $UNC_PATH | sed -e 's/\\/\//g'
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

---

*Original answer*

With sed:

```
$ echo '\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' 
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = re.sub(r'\\', r'/', r'\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu')
>>> print s
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, it is getting a little trickier when we manipulate the same via variables, the above values are read from variables during which the python interpreter chops off the "\" character during read, i tried repr and variable.decode('string_escape'), but to no avail.:(

Comment: You mean the string is a variable? Declare it as a raw string, i.e. `s = r'\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu'`.

Comment: The variable value comes from Jenkins, I cannot do the above

Comment: @mhawke, i will not be able to do this , $ UNC_PATH=\\\\test.abc.com\\path1\\path1_1\\123\\ubntu, since the value comes in the form of a variable, the moment i try to read the variable (say UNC_PATH which the user has mentioned as \\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu in Jenkins) python interprets the variable as \test.abc.compath1path1_1123ubntu, it chucks out the '\' character, got the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use other tools but translating characters is the job `tr` was created for:

```
$ tr '\\' '/' < file
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's~\\~/~g' file
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

Through Python,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu'
>>> print s
\\test.abc.com\path1\path1_1\123\ubntu
>>> m = re.sub(r'\\', r'/', s)
>>> print m
//test.abc.com/path1/path1_1/123/ubntu
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, it is getting a little trickier when we manipulate the same via variables, the above values are read from variables during which the python interpreter chops off the "\" character during read, i tried repr and variable.decode('string_escape'), but to no avail.:( – The Complete use case being: They are passed as Windows UNC Paths via jenkins, need to be mounted on Unix